# How to terminate background coverage Django runserver job in a shell script

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, shell

I get a [coverage](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) report when I execute this interactively in a terminal session:

```
coverage run manage.py runserver --noreload &
pid=$!
manage.py test tests.functional_tests 
/usr/bin/kill -s INT $pid
coverage report
```

But if I put the same lines in a bash script and execute it I get no coverage report:

```
cat > mytest.sh <<EOS
coverage run manage.py runserver --noreload &
pid=\$!
manage.py test tests.functional_tests 
/usr/bin/kill -s INT \$pid
coverage report
EOS
bash mytest.sh
```

Inside the bash script `/usr/bin/kill -s INT` does not terminate the Django development server. I've tried sending different signals (HUP, TERM, ABRT, QUIT) to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?